# Contains() acting different on List and TreeSet

Tags: scala, treeset

I've run into a weird case where the `contains()` function seems to work differently between a List and a TreeSet in Scala and I am not sure why or how to resolve it.

I've created a class called `DataStructure` for sake of brevity. It contains two elements: a coordinate pair `(i, j)` and an `Int`. (It's more complicated than that, but in this MWE, this is what it looks like) It has a custom comparator that will sort by the `Int`, and I have overridden `hashCode` and `equals` so that two elements containing the same coordinate pair `(i, j)` are treated as equal regardless of the `Int`.

When I put an instance of `DataStructure` into both a `List` and a `TreeSet`, the program has no problem finding exact matches. However, when checking for a new element that has the same coordinate pair, but different `Int`, the `List.contains` returns `true` while `TreeSet.contains` returns `false`. Why does this happen and how can I resolve it?

This is my code reduced to a minimum working example:

Class `DataStructure`

```
package foo

class DataStructure(e1: (Int, Int), e2: Int) extends Ordered[DataStructure] {
  val coord: (Int, Int) = e1
  val cost: Int = e2

  override def equals(that: Any): Boolean = {
    that match {
    case that: DataStructure => if (that.coord.hashCode() == this.coord.hashCode()) true else false
    case _ => false
  }}
  override def hashCode(): Int = this.coord.hashCode()

  def compare(that: DataStructure) = {
    if (this.cost == that.cost)
        0
    else if (this.cost > that.cost)
        -1  //reverse ordering
    else
        1
  }    
}
```

Driver program

```
package runtime

import foo.DataStructure
import scala.collection.mutable.TreeSet

object Main extends App {
        val ts = TreeSet[DataStructure]()

        val a = new DataStructure((2,2), 2)
        val b = new DataStructure((2,3), 1)

        ts.add(a)
        ts.add(b)

        val list = List(a, b)

        val listRes = list.contains(a)  // true
        val listRes2 = list.contains(new DataStructure((2,2), 0)) // true
        val tsRes = ts.contains(a)  // true
        val tsRes2 = ts.contains(new DataStructure((2,2), 0))  // FALSE!

        println("list contains exact match: " + listRes)
        println("list contains match on first element: " + listRes2)
        println("TreeSet contains exact match: " + tsRes)
        println("TreeSet contains match on first element: " + tsRes2)
}
```

Output:

```
list contains exact match: true
list contains match on first element: true
TreeSet contains exact match: true
TreeSet contains match on first element: false
```

Comment: You already have your answer, but I wanted to add that using hashcode as equals is a bad idea since you can have equal hashcodes on different objects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly `List.contains` is checking `equals` for each element to find a match, whereas `TreeSet.contains` is walking the tree and using `compare` to find a match.

Your problem is that your `compare` is not consistent with your `equals`. I don't know why you're doing that, but don't:

https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordered.html

"It is important that the equals method for an instance of Ordered[A] be consistent with the compare method."

Comment: Even in vanilla Java, the consistency between equals and compareTo is part of the Comparable contract, as the consistency between equals and hashCode is part of Object contract, so in such case the 3 must be consistent